# itemstyle-width not working in chrome,work in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following method for creating label in asp gridview. If I use like this the text will come in that label in `IE` but in `Chrome` and `FireFox` the text will go outer of the `grid-view`? 
How to solve this?

```xml
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="text" itemstyle-width="100px" >                                              
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"  Text='There is no null-terminating character at the end of a C# string; therefore a C# string can contain ... of s1 and s2 are concatenated to form a single string, the two original strings are unmodified. ... For more information about how to create new strings that are based on modifications ... string quote Regex pattern strings are also interpreted at runtime, like string.Format(...). The Regex syntax contains instructions that are introduced by \. E.g. \d stands for a single character from the set 0...9. I dnt go into the Regex syntax in this tip, but rather how to conveniently put such a Regex pattern into a C# string.'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can you include the html generated?

Comment: The code given in the question is not html it is asp.net. Can you include in your question the html the code generates? In the browser you are having issues with right-click=>view source

Comment: could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change
    itemstyle-width="100px"
to
    style="width: 100px;"